# Google is not indexing my site although it is crawling it

Tags: google, google-search-console, googlebot

I have a site that has around 12,000 pages. A couple of days ago I uploaded the site, I removed the `disallow` option from my *robots.txt*, I run "fetch as Google" and I got the message:

> URL and linked pages submitted to index.

The problem is that my site is not indexed yet although Google bot has started crawling it. When I search Google for my domain name I get:

> A description for this result is not available because of this site's *robots.txt*

I have removed the `disallow` option and in fact *robots.txt* is as follows for the last 2 days:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /
```

In fact, when I test the robots.txt file via the Webmaster Tools I get:

> Allowed
>   Detected as a directory; specific files may have different restrictions

Google is crawling it at a slow pace (~400 pages per day).

How can I can tell Google to index my site before finishing with the crawling process? If this is not possible, can I speed up the crawl?

Comment: Too soon to say that Google is not indexing your site. The crawl is a separate process from data analysis and SERP display. _A couple of days ago_ is followed by 1-4 weeks. After that point, you can start saying that Google isn't indexing anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have removed the disallow option and in fact *robots.txt* is empty for the last 2 days.

If your *robots.txt* files goes away or becomes empty, Google sometimes assumes that this is an error and won't honor the change for some time.  Instead of an empty *robots.txt* file, you should make one that explicitly allows everything:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

---

After you have changed your *robots.txt* file, Google usually takes at least a week and sometimes as much as a month to index a website.  You'll just have to wait it out.

If it hasn't crawled the entire website, it will index the pages that it has crawled before completing a crawl the entire site.

The only way to speed up crawl process is to increase the reputation of the site with more high quality inbound links.  The number of pages that Googlebot crawls and the rate it which it returns to re-crawl them are governed mainly by Pagerank.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tested my robots.txt through Webmaster tools and I got: Allowed
Detected as a directory; specific files may have different restrictions. Is it possible to just index the homepage?

Comment: If Googlbot is actively crawling your site then there isn't a problem with the *robots.txt* file.  Its just a matter of waiting until the content gets indexed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stephen. If this is the case then it can take months! Can I at least index the homepage?

Comment: You can't speed up Google in any way about this.  It shouldn't take months.  Maybe a month for some of the less popular pages on your site.  I'd be surprised if it took more than a week until the home page gets indexed.

Comment: Google finally indexed the homepage after 5 days! It seems I just have to wait! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Put the following into your robots.txt to tell Googlebot to crawl everything.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.   In this case Googlebot is already crawling everything.   Your robots.txt suggestion would be better with a blank disallow line (`Disallow: `) rather than an `Allow: /` line.   Most robots don't understand disallow.